# What is the purpose of the announcement_signatures message as specified by the Lightning Network RFC?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, ln-gossip

Isn't the `channel_announcement` message enough for channel advertisement? Why is the `announcement_signatures` message required?

Reference [BOLT #7](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md#the-announcement_signatures-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand the process the channel is constructed between two peers. For privacy reasons one of the two peers could decide to keep the channel private.

[Bolt7](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md#the-announcement_signatures-message) uses the following quote with a reference to the [open message of Bolt2](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#the-open_channel-message)

> The willingness of the initiating node to announce the channel is signaled during channel opening by setting the announce_channel bit in channel_flags (see [BOLT #2](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#the-open_channel-message)).

In that case the peer would not sign the channel and disalowing the other party to have a `channel_announcement` message. In this way the channel cannot be public as others would not react to the announcement as there are signatures missing.

So to summarize: the message with the signatures is a message between the channel partners allowing for a gossip message of the peer2peer protocol to announce the channel. Hope that made it clear (: